# How to add mulitple buttons to a Kivy Layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to a make a music player using Kivy, which will just have two button; one for play and one for pause. When I trying to bind a function to the buttons, when I press the buttons, I get errors. Upon searching this very own site for this, there was a suggestion to use the `partial` function from the `functools` library. But even that didn't work. My code is below.

```
class Layout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size = Window.size

        self.play = Button(text="Play", size_hint=(0.25, 0.25), font_size=36,  background_color=color,
                           pos=(self.size[0]*(3/8), self.size[1]*(4/10)) )
        self.pause = Button(text="Pause", size_hint=(0.25, 0.25), font_size=36, background_color=color,
                            pos=(self.size[0]*(3/8), self.size[1]*(1/10)) )
        self.play.bind(on_press=self.play)
        self.pause.bind(on_press=self.pause)
        self.add_widget(self.play)
        self.add_widget(self.pause)


    def play(self):
        print("PLay")

    def pause(self):
        print("Pause")
```

This gave this error

> AssertionError: <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x000001D1D4792CF0>
> is not callable

and by using the partial function

```
        self.play.bind(on_press=partial(self.play))
        self.pause.bind(on_press=partial(self.pause))
```

I get served this

> TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code. the first one is that you have given the event handlers and the buttons the same name. So change one of those. Second, you need a second parameter to event handlers as it gets called with a parameter.

Here is your corrected code:

```py
class Layout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size = Window.size

        self.play = Button(text="Play", size_hint=(0.25, 0.25), font_size=36,
                           pos=(self.size[0]*(3/8), self.size[1]*(4/10)) )
        self.pause = Button(text="Pause", size_hint=(0.25, 0.25), font_size=36,
                            pos=(self.size[0]*(3/8), self.size[1]*(1/10)) )

        self.play.bind(on_press=self.play1)
        self.pause.bind(on_press=self.pause1)

        self.add_widget(self.play)
        self.add_widget(self.pause)


    def play1(self, instance):
        
        print("PLay")

    def pause1(self,  instance):

        print("Pause")
```

If you don't want to add a parameter then you can use lambda function.
Something like this:

```py
self.play.bind(on_press=lambda _:self.play1())
self.pause.bind(on_press=lambda _:self.pause1())
```

In this case, you can remove the extra parameter in the eventhandler.

Comment: This worked! And now I will remember to keep different names for functions and variables :D